# Proof the the field of rational numbers has the Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I was tasked by the question to prove that the field of rational numbers has the Archimedean property

Proof:
Let $x$ and $y$ $\in$$ Q$ and $n$ be a positive integer. If $Q$ does not have the Archimedean property, then $nx\leq y$

For the case where $nx=y$, then $n+1\gt y$
however as $n+1$ is a positive integer then by contrapositive $Q$ must have the archimedean property

Is this valid and how can I phrase this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following is a bit cleaner:

Fix $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x>0$. We need to produce a positive integer $n$ with $nx>y$.

By definition of $\mathbb{Q}$, there are integers $a,b,c,d$ with $x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{c}{d}$ and $b>0$ and $d>0$.

As $x>0$, we have that $a>0$. Now, there are two cases:

- If $y\le 0$, then taking $n=1$ does the trick, since then $y\le 0<x=1x$.
- If $y>0$, then $c>0$. But then
  $$
  y=\frac{c}{d}\le c \le ac=bcx<bcx+x=(bc+1)x
  $$
  Since $bc+1$ is a positive integer, we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I feel your proof is in fact cleaner, but how do I make my future proofs have that level of clarity, as to me your writing is clear but i can't pinpoint exactly what makes it clear and how to translate that to future writing

Comment: @Burgercrazy I'm afraid there's no good answer for that. Practice helps, of course. I'd also suggest the following: after writing an argument, re read it to make sure that every step along the way follows clearly from the last. If that's not the case, break it down into more steps.

Comment: The point of finding $n$ directly is obvious that I couldn't see. By having $x/y = p/q$ for some $p, q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q > 0,$ the goal is to choose a number that is larger than this fraction $p/q.$ So, it seems that $p$ works as $p > p/q,$ but not really as $p$ may be negative, so let's choose $|p|,$ still there a case of the minimum $q = 1,$ so $|p| + 1$ does the job.

Comment: My own approach was unnecessarily longer. Assume that $\exists x, y\in\mathbb{Q}, y > 0;\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N};\,x\ge ny.$

$y > 0, y^{-1}\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow x/y\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow\exists p, q\in\mathbb{Z},\,q > 0;\,x/y = p/q.$

$x\ge ny\Leftrightarrow p/q = x/y\ge n\Leftrightarrow p - nq\ge 0.$

By the well ordering property, the subset $\{p, p - q, p - 2q, ..., p - nq, ...\}$ has a unique minimum, say $m = p - kq$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ However, as $p - (k + 1)q$ also belongs to the subset, it's necessary that $m \le p - kq - q = m - q\Rightarrow q\le 0.$ Contradiction.